# How do I get my contact list to display busines name also?

Tags: contacts

How do I get the names in my contact list to be displayed WITH their organization? b/c I have business contacts who I may never remember by name but may need to contact someone from their place of business.

Comment: Not possible with the stock Contacts app. You'll need a third-party app that displays the data differently.

Comment: You *could* put the business name in the "Last Name" field.

Answer (score 1):

Typing out an organization name in the main SEARCH box displays the relevant contacts that have the info in the Organization field.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to remove the information from the name field.  Then your business or your organization will be displayed in the contact list.

You can put the individual names of people in the company in the note's field.  You are basically saying the company is your contact entry, not the individual.

Of course you can also have other contacts in your list by person's names.  You can fill out Organization/Business info fields in those also.  When searching, you'll see their names in the list.

Comment: This might work for Android itself but we sync our contacts with Nextcloud (using DAVx⁵) and Nextcloud Contacts copies the company name to the name field if you leave it empty. So this ends up with the same as writing only the company name into the contact’s name.